# Merge the "google-picasa" and "picasa" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are 111 questions tagged [google-picasa](/questions/tagged/google-picasa), 95 questions tagged [picasa](/questions/tagged/picasa), and some  questions that use both the tags.
The tags should be merged.

Comment: Starting in on this now (I'm manually retagging to [tag:google-picasa]).

Comment: There is no need to manually do it; moderators can merge tags without editing 83 questions.

Comment: But until a mod DOES, and I have time I may choose to spend manually retagging, I don't see why I shouldn't do it.

Comment: Because you are bumping 83 questions to the front page, which would take the place of new questions. If you are going to do it, you should do it during weekends, and limiting the re-tag to groups of 5-6 questions at time.

Comment: I was checking the front page to make sure I didn't do that. In fact, I only bumped the most recent of the questions, from then on none of them got bumped automatically. Don't worry, I know how to do it considerately.